# Linux Bash expr index command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking how the `index` works in this case,
i know how `expr` normally works but not in combination with `index`.

For example:

```
X=“Hello World”, S=“acegiklnor”
echo 'expr index $S "$X"'
```

What is the output from this example?
And how does it work here?

Comment: The output is `expr index $S "$X"`, because nothing inside the single quotes is expanded.

Comment: Note that `“` are not `"`, probably a copy&paste problem.

Comment: Also, `index` is a GNU extension to the `expr` command, and its behavior is documented in the man page.

Comment: Maybe you meant `echo \`expr index $S "$X"\`` (backticks instead of single quotes)? It's enough to just use `expr index $S "$X"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: in the examples below I am using a single leading `$` to indicate a shell prompt. Any line that does not begin with `$` is output.

Your initial example contains a number of problems unrelated to the meaning of the index subcommand in GNU expr, I'm going to skip over them and just focus on index itself. As @chepner points out, other implementations of `expr` do not have the `index` function, such as on OS X.

If you read the help message for `expr` you can see the `index` operation.

```
$ expr --help | grep index
  index STRING CHARS         index in STRING where any CHARS is found, or 0
```

Using your example

```
$ X="Hello World"
$ S="acegiklnor"

$ expr index "$X" "$S"
2
```

2 is the 1-based index of the letter `e` in `Hello World`.

If you asked for a letter which didn't exist in the string, the result would be zero (and the exit status of expr would be `1`, indicating an unsuccessful exit).

```
$ expr index "$X" "z"
0
```

The result is the same if the second argument is the empty string.

```
$ expr index "$X" ""
0
```